# How can I make this code shorter but achieve more - Python - Email Validation Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, email

I am trying to create a program which validates an email, to check whether it is valid or not. One of my functions is to find out if there is a quote in the email, then separate the quote from the local section in the email and keep separating it until all the quotes are put into separate variables. What I have done so far is this:

```
local = help."hello"."a"
quote_list = local.split('"')
            print(quote_list)
            leng = len(quote_list)
            print(leng)
```

This code above is just to help the code below work properly 
This is the part that I need help with (see below):

```
            if leng == 3:
                quote = quote_list[1]
            if leng == 5:
                quote, quote_2 = quote_list[1], quote_list[3]
            if leng == 7:
                quote, quote_2, quote_3 = quote_list[3], quote_list[5], quote_list[3]
```

Is there any way to make the code shorter, and repeat for a longer number of times? Many Thanks
Hope you guys can find a way to fix this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please include a sample email data set in your question.

Comment: there is: **help."hello"."a"@gmail.com**

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

```py
quotes = [
    quote_list[i] for i in range(1, leng)
]
```

This will walk through your `quote_list` and pick up every second element starting at index 1 (= the second element).

Then you can process these quotes (now stored in `quotes`) in a next step.

---

But have in mind that this won't work so easily in general. As soon as s.o. forgets to close a single quote things will go wrong. (And s.o. *will* forget a quote at some time.) Additionally some email tools might use different kinds of quotes.

Comment: I just realiesed that I made a mistake in the example code that I showed you. I edited my question. Sorry for the inconvenience. Can you help me now? Thanks Regis May

Comment: I fixed it now. I added extra one extra number and it worked! Thankyou @Regis May SOOOO MUCH